# Magento2.4 move category.cms to destination content

Tags: magento2

I would like to move category.cms block from "category-view" to "columns".

I tried to do this:

1. mkdir -p app/design/frontend/Vendor/Namespace/Magento_Catalog/layout/
2. nano app/design/frontend/Vendor/Namespace/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```xml
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="category.cms" destination="content" after="-">
   </body>
</page>
```

3. Clear cache and refresh page.

Nothing change from my theme.
I use Magento 2.4 Luma

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<move element="category.cms" destination="columns" after="-" />
```

Comment: Hi, only <move tag or <page...><body><move...></body></page>? not works

Comment: Always add details of code like files to edit and line Or code section.

Comment: In this way? Not works

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="category.cms" destination="columns" after="-">
   </body>
</page>

Answer (score 0):

You have created your layout file in wrong path you should add file in below path

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Namespace/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

Add below code to move "category.cms" block.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="category.cms" destination="columns" after="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

FYI:- this block already called in columns.top in magento 2.4 luma theme. So you can add block name in before/after as per you want to set.

Comment: Sorry but I forgot the write Magento_Catalog/ on the path. Not work...

Comment: I have practically checked in magento 2.4.1 version and it is working properly. You should try to call this code in default file(vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml) first to check that it is working or not. If it is moved from default file then it is problem with the file creation in your theme.

Comment: First please put code <move element="category.cms" destination="columns" after="-"/> in body tag in default file vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml